# apache2 adding new website

Tags: html, apache, apache2

I'm pretty new to apache. I want to create a website hosting by apache, so here is what I did:
I created a new folder in /var/www/html named 'test'
I put my index.html, js and css files in the new folder

Then I tried to access the website by localhost/test, the html page displayed, but I cannot access the js and css files. In console it says "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/main.js"
Why '/test' is missing from the url?

My index.html has `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">`
Can anyone figure out what's wrong?

**UPDATE**
I checked dir.conf and added 'DirectorySlash on', now it looks like:

`<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
    DirectorySlash on
</IfModule>`

I noticed that when I try to access `http://localhost/test` it adds '/' to the end, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: "I noticed that when I try to access http://localhost/test it adds '/' to the end, but I'm still getting the same error." — All else being equal: that won't happen. You need to provide a [mcve] that has enough information in it to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a URL with a relative path, it is computed relative to the last `/` in the URL it is relative to.

Since you are visiting:

```
http://localhost/test
```

`test` is trimmed, and `main.js` is added.

If you were at

```
http://localhost/test/
```

then the last `/` is at the end, so it would resolve to `http://localhost/test/main.js`.

---

Apache would normally redirect you from `/test` to `/test/` if `test` was a directory (specifically to avoid this problem). You should edit your configuration files to enable [the directoryslash directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

```
DirectorySlash on
```

That's the default, but you must have a version with it disabled.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but I'm getting the same error. I updated what i have done. I installed apache2 from the command 'sudo apt-get install apache2' and I did nothing to it. Normally its all by default.